# Forward SSH connections based on user name

Tags: docker, ssh, proxy, port, reverse-proxy

I found numerous sites explaining *ssh port forwarding*, *ssh reverse proxy*, *ssh multiplexing* etc. involving `sshpiper`, `sslh`, *running a ssh socks server*, *just configuring the local SSH server* an so on.. 
so I'm quite puzzled right now and might ask a very common and/or simple question:

As you might already guess from the title I want to set up a git server (GitLab) inside a docker container listening for SSH connections on port 22 **without** having to use a different port for default ssh operations (terminal, scp, etc..) on the host (as suggested [here](https://thedockerexperts.com/blog/install-and-configure-gitlab-server-inside-docker/))

I.e.

- `ssh alice@myserver.org` should still be possible as well as
- `git clone git@myserver.com:path/to/project`
- and I don't want to do any setup on the client computer

If you prefer a picture:

```
                                      +------ myserver.org --------+
                                      |  +----+     +- typical -+  |
+--------+   alice@myserver.org:22    |  |    |     |   SSH     |  |
| client |  ---------------------->  -+--+----+---->|  service  |  |
+--------+     all names but `git`    |  | ?  |     +-----------+  |
                                      |  |    |                    |
                                      |  | ?  |     +- docker --+  |
+--------+   git@myserver.org:22      |  |    |     |   with    |  |
| client |  ---------------------->  -+--+----+---->|  GitLab   |  |
+--------+      only user `git`       |  |    |     |           |  |
                                      |  +----+     +-----------+  |
                                      +----------------------------+
```

Can you tell me what's the recommended/most common way to do this? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704418/forward-ssh-connection-of-single-user) question sounds promising but the answer seems to configure the client (which I want to avoid)

Comment: Hi I am the author of sshpiper. I think your problem is the typical scenario of sshpiper.

Comment: There are more similar questions on SE: https://serverfault.com/questions/569236/username-based-ssh-proxy https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260564/forward-ssh-for-git-user-to-git-server

Answer (score 1):

This project may help you.
https://github.com/tg123/sshpiper.

SSH Piper works as a proxy-like ware, and route connections by username, src ip , etc.

```
+---------+                      +------------------+          +-----------------+
|         |                      |                  |          |                 |
|   Bob   +----ssh -l bob----+   |   SSH Piper   +------------->   Bob' machine  |
|         |                  |   |               |  |          |                 |
+---------+                  |   |               |  |          +-----------------+
                             +---> pipe-by-name--+  |                             
+---------+                  |   |               |  |          +-----------------+
|         |                  |   |               |  |          |                 |
|  Alice  +----ssh -l alice--+   |               +------------->  Alice' machine |
|         |                      |                  |          |                 |
+---------+                      +------------------+          +-----------------+


 Downstream                         SSH Piper                       Upstream
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

First of all, thanks for reading [TheDockerExperts blog](https://thedockerexperts.com/blog/) , hope our articles help you! Let me explain how we do SSH proxy in our company.

We have HAproxy that listens TCP 22 port and sends traffic to GitLab server, on host we have custom SSH port. Unfortunately as we use TCP balancing in this case, there is no way to create balancer based on domain names and users. You can take small VPS , spin up HAproxy on it and use it to balance your GIT traffic.
Hope this will help you!

Comment: The OP didn't ask for load balancing or for a VPS product; they asked about port forwarding depending on the SSH user name. For me, this reads like blatant advertising with a repelling effect on the mentioned business because it fails to answer the user's question.